# How can I show the selected date and name of the day only after choosing it from the Datepickerdialog in android studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sdk, textview, datepickerdialog

I am having two layouts one for displaying the today's date and another one for displaying tomorrow's date using fragments. Currently I am getting today's date and name of the day(Saturday) correctly without any issue in the following format: 05-January-2019 Saturday.But I'm getting this date without choosing it from the datepicker dialog. This date is appearing automatically without any reason in the layout as soon as the datepicker dialog launches. But I need to get it only after choosing it from the datepicker dialog. How can I do it?

Here's my MainFragment class:

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout layout1, layout2, layout3, todayLayout, tomorrowLayout;
    ImageView calendarImgView;
    public static TextView todayDate, todayDay;
    Activity activity;
    public static final String TAG = PhotosFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

        activity = getActivity();

        Initialization(view);

        return view;


    }

    public void Initialization(View view) {

        layout1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout3 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        todayDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
        todayDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDay);
        todayLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.todayLayout);
        tomorrowLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tomorrowLayout);
        calendarImgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarImgView);
        calendarImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");


            }
        });

    }

    public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd - MMMM - yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            Date d = new Date();
            final String dayname = sdf.format(d);
            todayDay.setText(dayname);

            final String ma = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
            todayDate.setText(ma);
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
        }

        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {


        }

    }
}
```

I'm using the click event in imageView to trigger the event for datepicker dialog. Please let me know where the mistake is done? I am using two SimpleDateformat class one for getting the month and date and other for getting the day.Pls help me out.

Comment: So your problem is that the date automatically shows when you select `calendarImgView` ? If so, the reason is because you are setting todays date in `onCreateDialog` - `todayDay.setText(dayname);`.

Comment: If you don't want to set the date instantly, call it in `onDateSet` or `populateSetDate`.

Comment: @HB., thanks...worked!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.